# Loading and Saving Images From/To Database Using Data Binding

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I created 2 forms :

UserFrm : contains some textboxs, comboxs, a pictureBox and Buttons(Add, Edit, Remove).

UserListFrm : contains a DataGridView that load informations from the database.

My questions are :

1 - How can I save/edit/remove (the picture i load to the pictureBox) to the database using databinding.

2 - How can I load the picture to the DataGridView using Databinding.

**Note : I'm using C# as a programming language.**

Comment: please help me, i need this for my summer's project

Answer (score 0):

Image Column in GridView

```
 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Picture"> 
                        <ItemTemplate> 
                          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#    "Handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("Img_Id")  %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Handler.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"); 
  myConnection.Open(); 
  string sql = "Select Image_Content from ImageGallery where Img_Id=@ImageId"; 
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection); 
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageId",SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]); 
  cmd.Prepare(); 
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
  dr.Read();
  context.Response.ContentType = "jpeg";//dr["Image_Type"].ToString(); 
  context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image_Content"]); 

    }



   public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```